# Does this TPM emulator follow TPM spec for extending PCR register?

Tags: c, sha, tpm

The following code is from TPM emulator from Mario Strasser. The spec says,

```
PCR := SHA1(PCR || data)
```

reads "concatenate the old value of PCR with the data, hash the concatenated string and store the hash in PCR". It's not `PCR := PCR BITWISE-OR SHA1(data)` nor `PCR := SHA1(PCR BITWISE-OR data)`

```
TPM_RESULT TPM_Extend(TPM_PCRINDEX pcrNum, TPM_DIGEST *inDigest, 
                      TPM_PCRVALUE *outDigest)
{
  tpm_sha1_ctx_t ctx;

  info("TPM_Extend()");
  if (pcrNum >= TPM_NUM_PCR) return TPM_BADINDEX;
  if (!(PCR_ATTRIB[pcrNum].pcrExtendLocal & (1 << LOCALITY))) return TPM_BAD_LOCALITY;
  /* compute new PCR value as SHA-1(old PCR value || inDigest) */
  tpm_sha1_init(&ctx);
  tpm_sha1_update(&ctx, PCR_VALUE[pcrNum].digest, sizeof(PCR_VALUE[pcrNum].digest));
  tpm_sha1_update(&ctx, inDigest->digest, sizeof(inDigest->digest));
  tpm_sha1_final(&ctx, PCR_VALUE[pcrNum].digest);  
  /* set output digest */
  if (tpmData.permanent.flags.disable) {
    memset(outDigest->digest, 0, sizeof(*outDigest->digest));
  } else {
    memcpy(outDigest, &PCR_VALUE[pcrNum], sizeof(TPM_PCRVALUE));
  }
  return TPM_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, yes. See my comment in [Perform OR on two hash outputs of sha1sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706999/perform-or-on-two-hash-outputs-of-sha1sum)

Comment: honestly I dont know what internal hash state means. So basically what I wanted to do in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706999/perform-or-on-two-hash-outputs-of-sha1sum was incorrect. Thanks for pointing